# How to add an object file to every link

Tags: gcc, ld, specifications

There is a [bug in RHEL5's gcc-4.3.2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=493929) with which we are stuck. As a work-around we have extracted the missing object and put it in an object file. Adding this object file to every link makes the problem go away.

While adding it directly to `LDFLAGS` seems like a good solution, this doesn't work since e.g. `libtool` cannot cope with non-la files in there.

A slightly more portable solution seems to be to directly patch the gcc spec to add this to every link. I came up with

```
*startfile:
+ %{shared-libgcc:%{O*:%{!O0:/PATH/TO/ostream-inst.o}}}
```

where `ostream-inst.o` is added to the list of startfiles used in the link when compiling a shared library with optimizations.

Trying to compile boost with this spec gives some errors though since its build directly sets some objects with `ld`'s `--startgroup`/`--endgroup`.

How should I update that spec to cover that case as well, or even better, all cases?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this URL **[Specifying subprocesses and the switches to pass to them](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html)** and **[GCC Command Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC)**

If this help you, thats great.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear (since you specified otherwise in your question), but you are running into trouble here and are likely to run into more since your compiler is buggy. You *should* find a way of replacing it, since you'll find yourself writing even more work-around code the next time some obscure build system comes along. There's not only bjam out there.

Sorry I can't help you more. You might try simply writing a .lo file by hand (it's a two-liner, after all) and insert it into your LDFLAGS.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. My trouble is actually not with bjam, but only with the fancy flags used by boost's build. The whole point of patching the gcc spec was so that this fix can be used by multiple build systems (currently this works with automake, make, cmake and basic bjam). Stuffing a `*.lo` file into the LDFLAGS might seem fine, but that then breaks anything not using libtool (e.g. basic make). Then I'd rather stay with `libtool`'s warning about non-portability of linking non-libtool objects.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bug of GCC 4.3, did you try to build (by compiling from sources) and use a newer GCC. GCC 4.6.2 is coming right now. Did you consider using it?

Comment: Like I said, we cannot switch even though it's buggy. This is a government thing.